# ssh into localhost root permission

Tags: linux, ant, ssh, permissions, sudo

I am working on a project where the code is originally used to ssh into 4 other remote computers to run tests. I was given the task to run them on a single computer due to increased computing power.

normally the program ssh into root@computer1, does some copying and pasting

example one of the code in ant file is:

```
<target name="overwrite-config-file">
    <exec executable="bash" inputstring="echo '${database.password}' | sudo -S rm -rf ${config.file}" />
    <exec executable="bash" inputstring="echo '${database.password}' | sudo -S cat ${new.config.file} > ${config.file}" />
</target>
```

everything works fine when using root on other computers

now I am trying this on a single computer, I am doing so by creating 4 accounts to "simulate" the computer, i will ssh into computer1@localhost etc.

the problem is with root@computer1 all the copying and pasting work perfectly but with ssh into localhost i do not have the admin rights of root and everytime i try to do anything to the files it responds permission denied, as you can see i have sudo in these commands but still getting the permission denied error.

tl;dr: anyway to give a user root rights so permission wont be denied?

Comment: Have you rules out the possibility that ${database.password} is empty on localhost?  That would explain the "permission denied". Not that things run as root usually require sudo activities to begin with.  I think you didn't share part of the bigger picture :}

Comment: @tink unfortunately yes i have, i added an echo before the exec and it was able to give the correct password, i do notice the first line works, the 2nd line doesn't. from my research on it so far it seems to be because of the ">" but i have no clue how to replace it yet.

Comment: So - does the script switch to a different user once you kick it off? It may be as easy as prepending the ${config.file} with a ~/ to make it  ~/${config.file} (assuming the other user has a home). It all this is run as root I'd assume that, for some reason, the file-system is readonly.

Comment: @tink the ${config.file} points to /etc/filename.txt which is why the permission is denied when trying to cat into a file inside /etc folder as computer1@localhost

Comment: Can you try this? sudo -S sh -c "cat ${new.config.file} > ${config.file}" ? I have no idea what program is "executing" what to me looks like an XML file, or how it will respond to the extra quotes; this is just a stab in the dark that will most likely fail.